# Aligning mathematical "equations"

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to get the following output (this is just written using Google Docs):

[image]

I find that `align*` doesn't work here as there is no `=` present. Further, I would like this to be centralised, so I have not tried using `flalign*` (as my understanding is that `flalign*` can only be used to align equations to the left-hand-side).

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `align`, even without `=`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
              & \gcd(a, b) \,|\, a \text{ and } b \\
  \Rightarrow & \gcd(a, b) \,|\, ax + by \\
  \Rightarrow & \gcd(a, b) \,|\, d
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I was not aware you could use align like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using *align* like this should be working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  & \gcd(a,b) \mid a \ and \ b \\
 \Rightarrow & \gcd(a,b) \mid ax + by \\
 \Rightarrow & \gcd(a,b) \mid d
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it, it is well centered and looks like your picture.
Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, that works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It does work. Align the  | symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\gcd(a, b) & \mid a, b \\
\implies \gcd(a, b) & \mid ax + by \\
\implies \gcd(a, b) & \mid d
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was not aware that it could be used that way, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

These lines can be produced using the "eqnarray"-environment:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
   gcd(a,b) &|& a and b
 =>gcd(a,b) &|& ax + by
 =>gcd(a,b) &|& d
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Use the asterix (*) to suppress the numbering of the equations and the sign "&" on both of the sign which you want to center around.

Comment: For reference, see [`eqnarray` vs `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764).

Comment: Hm, I was not aware of this option. Thank you for the suggestion!